# Create temp table with duplicate data

Tags: postgresql, join, temp-tables

I have two tables (colors and numbers). I want to put them together in a certain format where each color has each number repeated as an entry.

My two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE colors (
color VARCHAR(20)
); 

INSERT INTO colors
     (color)
VALUES
     ("red"),
     ("green"),
     ("blue");

CREATE TABLE hours (
 hour NUMERIC
); 

INSERT INTO hours
     (hour)
VALUES
     (1),
     (2),
     (3),
     (4);
```

I want my output to look like:

```
Color   Hour  
red      1  
red      2
red      3
red      4
green    1
green    2
green    3
green    4
blue     1  
blue     2
blue     3
blue     4
```

Thanks for the help. I assume there is also some way loop way of doing this without using the numbers table. But not necessary.

Comment: For some theory see [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) and in particular [Cross join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Cross_join)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a `cross join`:

```
select c.color, h.hour
from colors c cross join
     hours h;
```

If the ordering matters, then use an `order by`.  This works for your example:

```
select c.color, h.hour
from colors c cross join
     hours h
order by c.color desc, h.hour;
```